# Return Back to app from browser Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a button in my mainactivity,after clicking it,it opens a new activity(Acitivity2).
And in that activity I am opening the browser.Here are the codes-

```
public class Activity2 : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.OpenBrowser();


    }


public void OpenBrowser()
    {

        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://google.com");
        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory)
            .AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
             }
    protected override  void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);        

    }
}
```

Now my question is after successful completion of opening the url in the browser,how to go back to the app,currently browser never closes.
Sorry it may be simple question,but i am really struggling with it

Comment: This is the equivalent of opening two apps, and you can only use the phone's physical return key or reopen the app,it's uncontrollable ! you could use webview to open the url,then you could control the rollback operation back to the app

Comment: Anyhow I have to use intent for opening url.could you please tell me  in mainactivity itself is it possible to use intent for opening URL and returning to app.

Comment: intent could open url,but could not control to returning to app

Comment: No its possible,how come users are logging out of the application and returning to browser

Comment: what do you mean "logging out of the application and returning to browser" ?

Comment: That means,a simple logout(it may be anytype of authentication like auth0,facebook etc)  from app in many cases when user clicks the logout button in app it opens default browser,then after url is opened ,it goes back to application

Comment: Sorry it was typo...In 2nd last comment ,I meant how come users are logging out of the application in browser and returning to app

Comment: those authentication pages have already done the authentication operation and callback of the return result, you need to call the corresponding authorization API in the application, but your ordinary intent to open a browser to open a url, your url page does not do anything related to your application, you are unable to control its behavior